# Can you add your bonus to Heightened Awareness attribute to your Attack Combat Value vs. hidden or invisible targets?

Tags: stealth, invisibility, besm, besm-3e

Can you add your bonus to Heightened Awareness attribute to your Attack Combat Value vs hidden or invisible targets?

Answer (score 1):

**Heightened Awareness mitigates penalties; it does not improve ACV.**

Normally, the penalty to hit an invisible, but revealed target is -3 for melee, -6 for ranged.  Each rank of Heightened Awareness reduces this penalty by 1, to a minimum of 0.

This rule is given in the text of the Invisibility power itself.